# Entity Framework throws DBUpdateConcurrencyException if table has trigger defined

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

While working on RESTful service in ASP.NET with support of Entity Framework and SQL Server 2014 as DB engine, I met some unexpected obstacle on my way.

I've prepared some dummy case which exactly explains what kind of problem I'm facing right now.

I've got database in SQL Server named "dummy_database". It contains only one table - Person - and one trigger - TR_Person_Insert - which is responsible for adding some extra data (current date and time in this particular case) to every single record before add the record to the "Person" table. Code of database structure is included below:

```sql
USE dummy_database;
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name LIKE 'person')
    DROP TABLE [person];
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE name LIKE 'TR_Person_Insert')
    DROP TRIGGER [TR_Person_Insert];
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[person]
(
    [id] INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    [name] NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    [surname] NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    [age] INT NOT NULL,
    [valid_from] DATETIME2 (7),

    CONSTRAINT PK_Person_ID PRIMARY KEY ([id])
)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER TR_Person_Insert ON [dbo].[person]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[person] ([name], [surname], [age], [valid_from])
    SELECT i.[name], i.[surname], i.[age], GETDATE()
    FROM inserted i
END
GO
```

Then I created dummy RESTful Service using ASP.NET and added Entity Framework with Database First approach to it. The code of one and only existing method of that Service is as below:

```c#
[RoutePrefix("api/person")]
public class DummyController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost, Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult AddPerson(PersonDto data)
    {
        using (var ctx = new DummyDatabaseModel())
        {
            var person = new person
            {
                name = data.Name,
                surname = data.Surname,
                age = data.Age
            };

            ctx.people.Add(person);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

The problem is with saving changes method called on database's context. This method throws DBUpdateConcurrencyException exception with additional information as below:

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.
```

I'm aware of the fact that this exception is caused by trigger, which is fired instead of regular 'insert' routine on database's side.

The question I ask is - how to get rid of this kind of exception without abandoning trigger in database. I'm out of ideas and to be frank - I count on your tips or solutions, if you faced same problem in the past.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you only want to store the insert date than you could put a default value of getdate() on that field and simply omit it from your columns in the insert statement. But that is a solution without the trigger which you did not want

Comment: It's just an example with datetime value, I would prefer to keep entire 'triggers' idea, as I use them not only in case of insert operations, but update and delete as well.

Comment: You could do a real insert trigger and in that do an update statement for all inserted records.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in my case, the trigger was the expression "instead of insert"

Ex.

```
Create trigger TR_AA on TbAA  INSTEAD OF INSERT ....
```

I changed the expression by "AFTER INSERT" It's work for me!

Ex.

```
Create trigger TR_AA on TbAA  AFTER INSERT ....
```